# Test Server for Eclipse IDE PHP 2020-06

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, zend-server, testserver

I'm new to PHP development and I'm facing some difficulties on installing a test server on the eclipse ide. Basically, i have installed wampserver x64 (apache 2.4, mysql 5.7 and PHP 7.0) with eclipse ide 2020-06 on a windows 10 machine. The problem is when i try to add a test server, what kind server should i choose? ZEND or APACHE? And what do i need to configure? After i choose apache as the default test server, i name it and locate the path, when comes to the debugger, i choose zend debugger and after i test it, the error will appear like this.

[image: 2]

[Which server should i choose? By right should be apache right?]

[image: 3]

I have already downloaded the zend debugger for php 7.0 and configured the php.ini file inside the apache ini file and the php 7.0 ini file which added at the end of the lines,

1. This is the path
   [zend]

   ```
        zend_extension=<C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.33\ext\ZendDebugger.dll>
        zend_debugger.allow_hosts=<127.0.0.1>
   ```

but still not no luck for me. Could someone enlighten me?
Million Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need to add a test server?

Comment: Image 1 and 2 are the same.

Comment: @Getset , i need to get a preview of my code to align with the web browser. I cant use tools like dreamweaver as my company got no budget for the development.

Comment: @howlget, my bad, i didnt realize it, but anyway that's the error generated.